# Occasionaly stuck during boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, thinkpad

I'm running a pretty vanilla 20.04 on a ThinkPad L490 and occasionally (I'd say it's about a 10% chance, I can't make out any pattern) it get's stuck during the boot process. I attached a picture of the error messages during boot:

[image: picture of the error messages during boot]

When this happens, I force a hard shutdown and reboot, which solved the problem every time.

On top of this, I changed my `/etc/default/grub` to contain:

```bsh
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=15
```

And the grub menu **always** shows up for 15 seconds. So I guess there is an error during boot every time, but it doesn't always get the boot stuck?

I tried un-commenting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, as was suggested in some similar posts, but to no effect.

Were could I go to debug this? I'm not really familiar with the boot and logging systems.

Comment: Some additional system information:
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- 64-bit
- Intel i5 (1.60GHz × 8)
- Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds this with the same problem: I made a fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04 and after copying over my old `~/.config` folder, I saw a similar boot problem (although not the grub menu). I then ended up doing a complete re-install of regular Ubuntu and moved to version 20.10 at the same time where I made sure the `~/.config` folder was not copied from my backup and the problems have not occurred since.

I am not sure, what exactly was the cause of the problems, but I assume it was either 20.04 specific or some configuration mistake on my part. So clearing out `~/.config` or upgrading Ubuntu to the next version should solve it.